# The program 'curl' is currently not installed Error! but can make a curl request from php

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

I am facing a strange issue in `ubuntu` when I hit this

```
curl -i -X POST -d '{"name":"kuldeep dangi", "Service_Request"}' http://localhost/index.php
```

from terminal I am receiving

```
The program 'curl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install curl
```

but when I make the same curl request using `PHP` I am getting the expected reult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl` is a linux utility that is run as a command from `bash`. This is not installed in your system. You can obvs install it by

```
sudo apt-get install curl       //for ubuntu, etc.
```

PHP curl command does the same thing but is a utility of PHP. When you install php in your system, it gets installed.
*I don't really know, but I think you installed php through LAMP

If you run something like:

```
shell_exec(curl *url*)
```

through php, it won't execute because you are trying to run curl from shell, which is not installed.

Comment: does it mean `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` is just a php curl module and `sudo apt-get install curl ` is the real curl extension for ubuntu

Comment: yes...bingo !! Because it is like this `php5-curl` for curl to work, that is why I thought that you installed php through LAMP or else you need to install it separately.

Comment: but isn't it PHP5-curl module will be using `curl` extension internally to make a curl request ?

Comment: No, it does not. When you read input in php through read, does it use shell read? No, its just a function of php.

Comment: Thank you vish for explanation.

Comment: And, why do you think it should?

Answer (score 0):

I tried several pattern but this one finally work. Basically this problem arise because of unfinished installation in your OS.
By the way, my OS is Xubuntu. (Ya. Old Soul)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

after finishing all the steps run :-

```
sudo aptitude install curl
```

I think this one help some people.
Thank you !!